# How to send a struct to new workers in Julia?

Tags: struct, parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

I have defined a struct that should be used as inputs for different functions which in turn are called from different workers. The field values will be changed in the functions, so I cannot construct them new between the function calls. How can I send the struct to new workers? I've tried `@eval @everywhere` and also `sendto` from the [ParallelDataTransfer](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl) package.

```
using Distributed
using Parameters

@with_kw struct Test
    path1::String = ""
    path2::String = ""
end

test = Test()
addprocs(2)
@eval @everywhere test = $test

Output:
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: Test not defined

using ParallelDataTransfer
sendto(workers(), test=test)

@everywhere print(test)

Output:
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: test not defined
```

I use Julia 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

All the code defining new types and methods should be known to all processes (and therefore be included in some way using an `@everywhere` clause). Otherwise, other processes don't know what `Test` refers to.

Overall, if I understand correctly what your trying to achieve, your example could look like the following:

```
julia> using Distributed

# Add new processes at first, so that they will be affected by subsequent
# @everywhere invocations
julia> addprocs(2)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3

# All code defining new types / methods should be evaluated in all processes
julia> @everywhere begin
           # This common code should probably live somewhere else, like in
           # another source file:
           #  include("some_file.jl")

           struct Test
               path1::String
           end

           path1(x::Test) = x.path1
       end

# Create the object in the master process
julia> x = Test("foo")
Test("foo")

# Send it to another one for processing
julia> f = @spawnat 2 path1(x)
Future(2, 1, 8, nothing)

# And get the answer back
julia> fetch(f)
"foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question is about mutating local `struct`s with remote workers.
You can not do that however you can send a copy of a new `struct`:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
using Parameters
@everywhere using Parameters
@everywhere begin
    @with_kw mutable struct Test
        a::String = ""
        b::String = ""
    end
end

t = Test(a="some")

@everywhere function mutate(t::Test)
    t.b = "newval"
    t
end

fut = @spawnat 2 mutate(t)
newt = fetch(fut)
```

Now you can see that newt contains a mutated copy of t:

```
julia> dump(newt)
Test
  a: String "some"
  b: String "newval"
```

However the value of `t` remains as it was:

```
julia> dump(t)
Test
  a: String "some"
  b: String ""
```

However you *can* mutate arrays of bit-based types if the workers are on the same host. (This example assumes that the workers have been added using the previous code):

```
using SharedArrays
@everywhere using SharedArrays

sa = SharedArray([1,2,3,4])

@everywhere function mutate(sa::SharedArray)
    sa[myid()] = myid()*100;
    return nothing
end

fetch(@spawnat 2 mutate(sa))
```

Now let's see the array:

```
julia> display(sa)
4-element SharedArray{Int64,1}:
   1
 200
   3
   4
```